# ROR: undefined method `jwt_revoked?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm inheriting a ruby on rails API and am not well known with ruby at all. So please forgive me if I am incomplete or unclear about my problem description.

When requesting a graphQl schema, the API checks a user on a provided JWT.
The environment makes use of a Devise Gem.

The user includes this gem:

```
include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::JTIMatcher
```

devise is set up like so:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :registerable,
         :recoverable, 
         :rememberable, 
         :validatable, 
         :jwt_authenticatable, 
         jwt_revocation_strategy: self
```

and it seems as though the token is checked by:

```
def token
    headers = { 
      'Accept' => 'application/json', 
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json' 
    }
    scope ||= Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(self)
    aud ||= headers[Warden::JWTAuth.config.aud_header]
    token, payload = Warden::JWTAuth::UserEncoder.new.call(
      self, scope, aud
    )
    token
  end
```

The error I receive is:

```
"undefined method `jwt_revoked?' for \"User\":String"
```

it happens in this piece of code:

```
    def execute
      variables = ensure_hash(params[:variables])
      query = params[:query]
      operation_name = params[:operationName]
      context = {
       current_user: current_user,
       login: method(:sign_in)
      }
      puts query
      result = GraphqlSchema.execute(
        query, 
        variables: variables, 
        context: context, 
        operation_name: operation_name
      )
      puts result.to_json
      render json: result
    rescue => e
      raise e unless Rails.env.development?
      handle_error_in_development e
    end
```

and seems to break when calling on `current_user`

the stacktrace is as follows:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-jwt_auth-0.3.6/lib/warden/jwt_auth/user_decoder.rb:51:in `check_valid_user'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-jwt_auth-0.3.6/lib/warden/jwt_auth/user_decoder.rb:36:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-jwt_auth-0.3.6/lib/warden/jwt_auth/strategy.rb:22:in `authenticate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/strategies/base.rb:55:in `_run!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/proxy.rb:372:in `block in _run_strategies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/proxy.rb:365:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/proxy.rb:365:in `_run_strategies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/proxy.rb:335:in `_perform_authentication'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/proxy.rb:110:in `authenticate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:126:in `current_user'
/.../app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb:8:in `execute'
```

further more, I created a JWT token and set it in my env variables;

this is set in the Devise setup like so:

```
  config.jwt do |jwt|
    jwt.secret = ENV['DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY']
    jwt.expiration_time = 42.day.to_i
  end
```

the 'devise' versions I use are:

```
gem 'devise'                                # Use devise as authentication module
gem 'devise-jwt', '~> 0.5.8'                # Use JWT token authentication with devise
```

and the ruby version is: 2.6.3.

Hopefully someone can help me along here :)

Comment: current_user should be the logged in user.  The fact the current_user is set to the string "User" leads me to believe that this is either happening because a) of a badly written test or b) the code never worked in the first place.

Comment: So i think that the current user is initialized here:



        def current_user
            context[:current_user]
        end

is that as supposed

Comment: What sets the context[:current_user]?

Comment: in "base.rb" the structure is:

module Resolvers
    class Base < GraphQL::Schema::Resolver
        def current_user
            context[:current_user]
        end
    end
end